# Mouse clicks and keyboard suddenly stop working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

For some reason while I am working, my mouse clicks and keyboard stop working for few minutes. Movement is fine, but the mouse buttons don't work. I can switch between tabs but no effect if I click/scroll/press keys.

Initially, I thought it could be the RAM limit but I checked system monitor and 50% RAM was free.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does keyboard and mouse use batteries? If USB have you tried other USB ports?  Has mouse been cleaned recently?

Comment: yeah, everything is cleaned. Even my touchpad won't work so I don't think it's port or cleaning issue.

Comment: Does this happen on different programs/apps or just one?  Computer specs might be helpful also.  Is this a new recent problem or has it always happen with 18.04?

Comment: Different programs. I am using Dell Inspiron 5570 i7, 10th gen, 16GB RAM, 256 SSD. It's a recent problem I started facing a month ago

Comment: Did a little googling and seems these types of problems don't seem to have a good answer.  Your google might turn out better.  It almost sounds like hardware(weak battery, partial broken/loose wire), but doubt that since it is mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I tried to google it before posting question here and came up with no effective solution. I purchased this laptop in October last year.

Comment: Only things I can think of doing is seeing if there is a bios update or try dell forums.  They might have some ideas.

Comment: yup, thank you for looking into it :)